# cut out part of a string

Tags: javascript, string, split

Say, I have a string

```
"hello is it me you're looking for"
```

I want to cut part of this string out and return the new string, something like

```
s = string.cut(0,3);
```

s would now be equal to:

```
"lo is it me you're looking for"
```

**EDIT**: It may not be from 0 to 3. It could be from 5 to 7.

```
s = string.cut(5,7);
```

would return

```
"hellos it me you're looking for"
```

Comment: Just curious... the String.substr() method seems to work for most scenarios I encounter - however you seem to have a need to remove a "middle" string bit - do you have a sample "real world" case where this occurs regularly?

Comment: Why wouldn't you cut 0-2 and 5-6 instead?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You're almost there. What you want is:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

So, in your example:

```
Var string = "hello is it me you're looking for";
s = string.substr(3);
```

As only providing a start (the first arg) takes from that index to the end of the string.

Update, how about something like:

```
function cut(str, cutStart, cutEnd){
  return str.substr(0,cutStart) + str.substr(cutEnd+1);
}
```

Comment: This function has an issue with line breaks, i suggest using substring and not substr like advised below  return this.substring(0, cutStart)+this.substring(cutEnd);

Answer (score 8):

Use

[substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/substring)

function

> Returns a subset of a string between
>   one index and another, or through the
>   end of the string.

```
substring(indexA, [indexB]);
```

**indexA**

```
An integer between 0 and one less than the length of the string.
```

**indexB** 
    (optional) An integer between 0 and the length of the string.

substring extracts characters from indexA up to but not including indexB. In particular:

```
* If indexA equals indexB, substring returns an empty string.
* If indexB is omitted, substring extracts characters to the end 
  of the string.
* If either argument is less than 0 or is NaN, it is treated as if 
  it were 0.
* If either argument is greater than stringName.length, it is treated as 
  if it were stringName.length.
```

If indexA is larger than indexB, then the effect of substring is as if the two arguments were swapped; for example, str.substring(1, 0) == str.substring(0, 1).

Answer (score 5):

Some other more modern alternatives are:

1. Split and join

   ```
   function cutFromString(oldStr, fullStr) {
     return fullStr.split(oldStr).join('');
   }
   cutFromString('there ', 'Hello there world!'); // "Hello world!"
   ```

   <sub>Adapted from [MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)</sub>
2. [String.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace), which uses regex. This means it can be more flexible with case sensitivity.

   ```
   function cutFromString(oldStrRegex, fullStr) {
     return fullStr.replace(oldStrRegex, '');
   }
   cutFromString(/there /i , 'Hello THERE world!'); // "Hello world!"
   ```

Answer (score 4):

```
s = string.cut(5,7);
```

I'd prefer to do it as a separate function, but if you really want to be able to call it directly on a String from the prototype:

```
String.prototype.cut= function(i0, i1) {
    return this.substring(0, i0)+this.substring(i1);
}
```

Comment: This is javascript ? substring

Answer (score 3):

string.substring() is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a reference for anyone looking for similar function, I have a String.prototype.bisect implementation that splits a string 3-ways using a regex/string delimiter and returns the before,delimiter-match and after parts of the string....

```
/*
      Splits a string 3-ways along delimiter.
      Delimiter can be a regex or a string.
      Returns an array with [before,delimiter,after]
*/
String.prototype.bisect = function( delimiter){
  var i,m,l=1;
  if(typeof delimiter == 'string') i = this.indexOf(delimiter);
  if(delimiter.exec){
     m = this.match(delimiter);
     i = m.index;
     l = m[0].length
  }
  if(!i) i = this.length/2;
  var res=[],temp;
  if(temp = this.substring(0,i)) res.push(temp);
  if(temp = this.substr(i,l)) res.push(temp);
  if(temp = this.substring(i+l)) res.push(temp);
  if(res.length == 3) return res;
  return null;
};

/* though one could achieve similar and more optimal results for above with: */

"my string to split and get the before after splitting on and once".split(/and(.+)/,2) 

// outputs => ["my string to split ", " get the before after splitting on and once"]
```

As stated here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Objects/String/split

> If separator is a regular expression that contains capturing parentheses, then each time separator is matched the results (including any undefined results) of the capturing parentheses are spliced into the output array. **However, not all browsers support this capability.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the following:

```
var s = "I am a string";

var sSubstring = s.substring(2); // sSubstring now equals "am a string".
```

You have two options about how to go about it:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#substring

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#substr

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var str="hello is it me you're looking for";
document.write(str.substring(3)+"<br />");
```

You can check [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp)

Answer (score 0):

this works well

```
function stringCutter(str,cutCount,caretPos){
    let firstPart = str.substring(0,caretPos-cutCount);
    let secondPart = str.substring(caretPos,str.length);
    return firstPart + secondPart;
   }
```