# Replace contant of an array in a string with a text-JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
let message ="hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";
let url=["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];
```

I want to put text `"***"` in place of all url found in the message array from url array.

Tried this way -

```js
let message = "hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";
let url = ["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];
const replace = url.map(item => {
  let indexes = message.indexOf(item);
  let output = message.replaceAt(indexes, "***")
})
```

Error-message.replace is not a function,also if the logic is correct?
Thanks!

Comment: You're not returning anything from your `map` callback. Did you mean `forEach`? `map` returns a new array, `forEach` work in-place.

Answer (score 1):

**1)** You can easily achive the result using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let message =
  "hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";

let url = ["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];

const result = url.reduce((msg, str) => msg.replace(new RegExp(str, "g"), "***"), message);

console.log(result);
```

**2)** You can also achieve the solution with [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) loop

```js
let message =
  "hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";

let url = ["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];

url.forEach((s) => (message = message.replace(new RegExp(s, "g"), "***")));

console.log(message);
```

**3)** Using [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

```js
let message =
  "hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";

let url = ["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];

const result = url.reduce((msg, str) => {
  while (msg.indexOf(str) !== -1) msg = msg.replace(str, "***");
  return msg;
}, message);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: good solution))

Comment: @HR01M8055 thank you, is there a way that I don't have use regx?

Comment: You can but that would be hard to understand and maintain as compared to `RegExp`

Comment: This solution is direct and efficient. But at the end of day you have to replace the string with some text and you gonna use `replace`

Comment: Though I've added one more solution. But still I'd prefer either `1` or `2`

Comment: Would you mind If you can [upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up#:~:text=How%20do%20I%20vote%20up,arrow%20to%20undo%20a%20downvote.) and [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The error is correct. replaceAt isn't a function, you're gonna have to use something like string `substr()` and then add your string inside, unless you think the string `replace()` method is good for your situation. I don't know enough about your case to decide.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707527/cut-out-part-of-a-string) might be useful, but make sure you actually add in the "***" after you cut out part of the string.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you can just use `replace` instead of `replaceAt`.
For example:

```js
let message = "hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com";
let url = ["https://ggogle.com", "https://yahoo.com", "http://web.com"];
const replace = url.map(item => {
    message = message.replace(item, "***")
})

console.log(message);
```

Comment: If you are not using the return value of `map` then It would be better to use `forEach`

Comment: What if the input is `"hello https://ggogle.com parul https://yahoo.com and http://web.com and https://ggogle.com"`. Then your snippet is not as expected...